# C# Multiple If Statements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I had been working in Unity 2D to try and write programming for a top down RPG. The problem I've run into is that C# does not seem to understand my if statements. I have set up multiple if statements and a single else statement, but the else statement only takes effect on the statement written just above it. Its kind of like the other if statements are pushed off to the side as seperate lines of code, even though i want the else to take effect on all of the if statements. I'm sorry if this sounds confusing, I'll just place my code below if you can figure out the problem.

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    //directional movement
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W)) {
        this.transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed);
        anim.SetBool ("moving", true);

    }if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) {
        this.transform.Translate(Vector2.right * -speed);
        anim.SetBool ("moving", true);
        anim.SetBool ("facingRight", false);

    }if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S)) {
        this.transform.Translate (Vector2.up * -speed);
        anim.SetBool ("moving", true);

    }if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) {
        this.transform.Translate (Vector2.right * speed);
        anim.SetBool ("moving", true);
        anim.SetBool ("facingRight", true);

    } else{
        anim.SetBool ("moving", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is C# expected behaviour, use IF - ELSE IF - ELSE

Answer (score 4):

```
if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W)) {
    this.transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed);
    anim.SetBool ("moving", true);

} else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) {
    this.transform.Translate(Vector2.right * -speed);
    anim.SetBool ("moving", true);
    anim.SetBool ("facingRight", false);

} else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S)) {
    this.transform.Translate (Vector2.up * -speed);
    anim.SetBool ("moving", true);

} else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) {
    this.transform.Translate (Vector2.right * speed);
    anim.SetBool ("moving", true);
    anim.SetBool ("facingRight", true);

} else{
    anim.SetBool ("moving", false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a series of `else if` statements as in aush's answer. Alternatively, consider `switch`

```
KeyCode kc = Input.GetKey();
switch (kc) {
    case KeyCode.W:
        this.transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed);
        break;
    case KeyCode.A:
        this.transform.Translate(Vector2.right * -speed);
        anim.SetBool ("moving", true);
        anim.SetBool ("facingRight", false);
        break;
    case KeyCode.S:
        this.transform.Translate (Vector2.up * -speed);
        anim.SetBool ("moving", true);
        break;
    case KeyCode.D:
        this.transform.Translate (Vector2.right * speed);
        anim.SetBool ("moving", true);
        anim.SetBool ("facingRight", true);
        break;
    default:
        anim.SetBool ("moving", false);
        break;
}
```

I find switch blocks easier to read than a series of else-ifs, personally. default will execute if none of the cases are met.

Also if you use `else-if` or `switch`, your code will not allow for the parsing of multiple button presses, such as up and right at the same time. If you don't have diagonals then that makes sense.